# How does one count specific individual text strings inside a range of cells, in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Let's say I have the following three rows under one column (column A):

☑︎ ☑︎ ☑︎ ☑︎ ☑︎ ☑︎ ☐ ☐

☑︎ ☑︎ ☑︎ ☐ ☐ ☐ ☐ ☐

☑︎ ☑︎ ☐ ☐ ☐ ☐ ☐ ☐

I'm looking to count the number of ☑︎ in the range A1 to A3, in this case it would be "11".

I tried the formula =COUNTA(A1:A3,"☑︎") but strangely, it returns "4".

Why is that, and more importantly, how does one get the correct answer of "11"?

Comment: Please share a link to your sheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should split text and then use `COUNTIF`:

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF(SPLIT(A1:A3," "),"☑︎"))
```

If there is no space between the checkboxes, the formula will become more complicated:

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A3&"","(?s)(.{1})","$1"&CHAR(127)),"'","''"),CHAR(127)),"☑︎"))
```

[image]